# What is the difference between CGContextAddLineToPoint and addLineToPoint function in UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d, uibezierpath

I have rendered some basic shapes using quartz-2d. I came across two methods to draw a line. First is to get a context using `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` and then draw the line using `CGContextAddLineToPoint`.

And other way is to define a `UIBezierPath` object and draw using its function `addLineToPoint`

```
[bezierPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
```

And then I have to add bezierPath to the context using `CGContextAddPath`.

So I wanted to know the difference between these two approaches as both are used to draw only a line. Is there a performance issue between these two? Also which method is better under what circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIBezierPath` is an object from the `UIKit`, and allow you to use a set of function mixing particular curve with control point but also with a normal line.

Being an object from the `UIKit` you are not able to use `CGContextAddLineToPoint`, but anyway at the end you need to add the path in the context with `CGContextAddPath`.

With `CGContexAddLineToPoint` instead you draw **directly on the context**.

So my suggest is to **use this last way** if you have not particular reasons (like amazing curve with different control point). Otherwise, use `UIBezierPath`.

Answer (score 2):

The `CGContextAdd..` functions are lower-level C Quartz2D API that bridge between `CGContext` and `CGPathRef` instances. You use a `CGContext` when you want to draw something, while `CGPathRef` is the structure that manages geometric shapes.

On the other hand, `UIBezierPath` is an Objective-C `UIKit` class that wraps around CGPath, and provides also some bridge to `CGContext` functions, for example with `setFill`, `setStroke`, `fill` or `stroke` methods.

Is totally safe to mix the two approaches, but it's sure that CGContext gives you more tools. Performance and memory are better with direct CGContext calls, but performance difference are absolutely negligible in 99% of the cases.